How i can do a conditional Count inside my C# console application
I have this .NET 8 console application:-
            var workOrderList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Work Orders", p => p.Title,
                                                                 p => p.Fields.QueryProperties(p => p.InternalName,
                                                                                               p => p.FieldTypeKind,
                                                                                               p => p.TypeAsString,
                                                                                               p => p.Title));

            // Build a query that only returns these fields for the Work Orders
            string viewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                    <ViewFields>
                      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                      <FieldRef Name='Created' />
                      <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                        <FieldRef Name='WorkOrderStatus' />
                        <FieldRef Name='WorkOrderType' />
                        <FieldRef Name='TechnicianName' />
                        <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                        <FieldRef Name='AssetID' />
                    </ViewFields>
                    <Query>
<Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
        <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
</Eq>
                    </Query>
                   </View>";

            // Load all the needed data using paged requests
            bool paging = true;
            string nextPage = null;
            while (paging)
            {
                var output = await workOrderList.LoadListDataAsStreamAsync(new RenderListDataOptions()
                {
                    ViewXml = viewXml,
                    RenderOptions = RenderListDataOptionsFlags.ListData,
                    Paging = nextPage ?? null,
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (output.ContainsKey("NextHref"))
                {
                    nextPage = output["NextHref"].ToString().Substring(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    paging = false;
                }
            }


 var groupedWorkOrders = workOrderList.Items.AsRequested().Where(a => (a["WorkOrderType"] != null && a["WorkOrderType"].ToString() == "Cleaning") || (a["WorkOrderType"] != null && a["WorkOrderType"].ToString() == "Maintenance"))
.Select(wo =>
{
    // Attempt to safely get each property, providing defaults for missing or null values
    var technicianName = wo["TechnicianName"] != null ? TechNameID.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == (wo["TechnicianName"] as FieldUserValue).LookupId.ToString()).Value : string.Empty;
    var workOrderStatus = wo["WorkOrderStatus"] != null ? wo["WorkOrderStatus"].ToString() : string.Empty;
    var createdStr = wo["Created"] != null ? wo["Created"].ToString() : null;
    DateTime.TryParse(createdStr, out DateTime created); // Defaults to DateTime.MinValue if parsing fails
    var assetId = wo["AssetID"] != null ? wo["AssetID"].ToString() : null;

    var mediumID = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(assetId) && AssetIdMediumMap.TryGetValue(assetId, out var mid) ? mid : string.Empty;

    return new
    {
        TechnicianName = technicianName,
        WorkOrderStatus = workOrderStatus,
        Year = created.Year,
        Month = created.Month,
        MediumID = mediumID,
    };
})
// Ensure that you're grouping by a composite key of all the fields
.GroupBy(wo => new { wo.TechnicianName, wo.Year, wo.Month, wo.MediumID })
.Select(g => new
{
    TechnicianName = g.Key.TechnicianName,
    Year = g.Key.Year,
    Month = g.Key.Month,
    MediumID = g.Key.MediumID,
    TotalCount = g.Count(),
    DoneCount = g.Count(wo => wo.WorkOrderStatus == "Done")
})
.ToList(); // Materialize the query to a list

now i am getting the totalcount and the DoneCount.. but we have 2 Media IDs (10 & 20) which have a weight of 1/2.. so, when counting those i need to consider that their weight on the totals is 1/2 while other media have a weight od 1. so how i can achieve this?
Thanks

Simply create a function that iterates through your list and counts by applying your ratio. It's pretty basic

Don't use Count; it doesn't understand anything non binary. Consider Sum instead:, for example DoneCount = g.Where(wo => wo.WorkOrderStatus == "Done").Sum(so => wo.MediumId == 10 || wo.MediumId == 20 ? 0.5 : 1)

Similar to answer by @flackoverstow but using pattern matching.
var doneCount = 
    g.Where(wo => wo.WorkOrderStatus == "Done")
    .Sum(
        wo => wo switch 
        {
            { MediumId: 10 or 20 } => 0.5,
            _ => 1
        }
    );

